# Loading .wav into a Audio Buffer

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to create a little web-app in javascript which plays some random chords by playing multiple audio files for each note at the same time.

I found out that this does not work if I use the normal "Audio" class because they don't play simultaneously. (Not reliable) Therefore I want to use the Web Audio API. But here I run into a problem:
How do I convert my "Audio()"-object (or any ".wav" file) into a AudioBuffer?

```
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var audioElement = new Audio("sounds/cut/24.wav");

myArrayBuffer = someUnknownFunction(audioElement);
//Alternative: myArrayBuffer = someOtherUnknownFunction("sounds/cut/24.wav")

var track = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
track.buffer = myArrayBuffer;
track.connect(audioCtx.destination);
track.start(0);
```

Does anyone know, what this "someUnknownFuntion(Audio)" could be?

Comment: [createMediaStreamSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want track to be an "AudioBufferSourceNode".

Answer (score 4):

You might want to read [BaseAudioContext.decodeAudioData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData)

Basically, you need specify the source using the `BaseAudioContext.decodeAudioData()` function:

```
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var audioFile = fetch("sounds/cut/24.wav").then(response => response.arrayBuffer()).then(buffer => audioCtx.decodeAudioData(buffer)).then(buffer => {
    var track = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    track.buffer = buffer;
    track.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    track.start(0);
});
```

I stole the `fetch` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45921431/fetch-external-audio-file-into-web-audio-api-buffer-cors-error).

Comment: First of all: thank you a lot. When trying to fetch(...) I get an error. I'm not sure why but maybe it's because my code is not uploaded to any server and the file needs to be fetched directly from my hardrive using the relative URL="sounds/cut/24.wav". This was no issue when using "var audioElement = new Audio("sounds/cut/24.wav");" but maybe for fetch("sounds/cut/24.wav") it is?

Comment: @NiciAdam Are you running a `localhost` server or opening the file straight from your browser like `file:///C:/`

Comment: like  `file:///C:/`

Comment: @NiciAdam then you can’t do this. You need to install local web server like Apache. I use XAMPP. You can google XAMPP and install it. You then need to store your files inside of C:/XAMPP/htdocs/. From there, run XAMPP as an administrator and run Apache. Then go to your website by typing in localhost or 127.0.0.1